# libpq c postgres interface crash

Tags: c, postgresql, dll, libpq

I'm a IT student doing some **C postgres** interface.
Using codelite  I'm doing the following on a **win10** machine:

- compile settings .include path : ".../postgresql/../include"  and
  I've changed the backslashes from \ to /
- link settings .library search path : "../postgresql/../lib"
- linker options "-lpq"

Running a standard following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <string>

int     main() {
PGconn          *conn;
PGresult        *res;
int             rec_count;
int             row;
int             col;



    conn = PQconnectdb("dbname=ljdata host=localhost ser=dataman                        password=postgre");

    if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
            puts("We were unable to connect to the database");
            exit(0);
    }

   res = PQexec(conn,
            "update people set phonenumber=\'5055559999\' where id=3");

     res = PQexec(conn,
             "select lastname,firstname,phonenumber from people order by id");

     if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
             puts("We did not get any data!");
             exit(0);
     }

     rec_count = PQntuples(res);

    printf("We received %d records.\n", rec_count);
     puts("==========================");

     for (row=0; row<rec_count; row++) {
             for (col=0; col<3; col++) {
                     printf("%s\t", PQgetvalue(res, row, col));
             }
             puts("");
     }

     puts("==========================");

     PQclear(res);

     PQfinish(conn);

     return 0;
     }
```

It should tell me that is connected or not on a simple console output.

But the console window of the exe file crashed **libpq.dll not found**,
after copying the **.dll** from **bin (postgres)** to include,

4 more dll are missing:

1. libintl-8.dll
2. libeay32.dll
3. ssleay32.dll
4. krb5_32.dll

What should I do? Copy all of the dll from postgres directory to some windows directory?

If anyone can point me how to configure codeblocks so that it links **libpq-fe.h**, I would apreciate alot.

Comment: The DLL files needs to be in the same directory as the executable file, or in a system directory where Windows searches by default.

Comment: 4 more missing after copy paste dlls to the same exe folder  comerr32.dll gssapi32.dll libiconv-2.dll

Comment: unfortunately krb5_32.dll is not in postgres folder nor commer32 ,gssapi32, only the libiconv is.         but we are getting closer .